# Input:Checked jQuery vs CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Unless I am mistaken. jQuery and CSS handle the `:checked` selector very differently. In CSS when I use `:checked`, styles are applied appropriately as I click around, but in jQuery it only seems to recognize what was originally in the DOM on page-load. Am I missing something?

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cssguru/8rDXd/)

In jQuery:

```
$('input:checked').click(function () { 
   $('input:checked').css('background','#FF0000');
   $('input:checked+label').css('background','#ff0000');
});
```

In CSS:

```
input:checked+label {font-weight:bold;color:#5EAF1E}
```

**UPDATE:**
I should clarify that what I am looking to do is trigger behavior if a user clicks an already selected radio button.

Comment: That's exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AFTER UPDATE

Keep track of the status of the radio buttons. For example, use `.data()` to keep an in-memory state of the radio buttons.

```
$(function () {
    var $radio = $(":radio");
    $radio.filter(":checked").data("checked", true);
    $radio.on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).data("checked")) {
            alert("Already selected");
        }
        $radio.data("checked", false).filter(":checked").data("checked", true);
    });
});
```

[See it live here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hDKXF/)

---

### BEFORE UPDATE

I think you want to use `.change()` here.

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
    $('input, input+label').css('background', '');
    $('input:checked, input:checked+label').css('background', '#f00');
}).change();
```

<s>[See it live here.](http://jsfiddle.net/BWQED/)</s>

Comment: See my update above...  I'm looking for a way trigger behavior when a checked radio button is clicked.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting up the handler this way:

```
$('body').on('click', 'input:checked', function() {
  // ...
});
```

The way you have it, you're finding all the elements that are checked *when that code runs*.  The above uses event bubbling so that the test is made when each "click" happens.

Inside your handler, you're updating the style for *all* checked elements, even though any particular click will only change one.  That's not a huge deal if the number of checkboxes isn't too big.

*edit* — some further thought, and a helpful followup question, makes me realize that inside an event handler for a radio button "click" event, the button will *always* be ":checked".  The value of the "checked" property is updated by the browser before the event is dispatched. (That'll be reversed if the default action of the event is prevented.)

I think it'll be necessary to add a class or use `.data()` to keep track of a shadow for the "checked" property.  When a button is clicked, you'd see if your own flag is set; if so, that means the button was set before being clicked. If not, you set the flag.  You'll also want to clear the flag of all like-named radio buttons.

Comment: The real problem seems to be that the listener is applied only on inputed checked instead of all input. the `.click(..)` method is an alias to the `.on(..)` regarding the documentation : http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @user1073122 yes, `.click` is an alias for `.on`, but when `.on` is called with **three** parameters as it is here, the semantics are quite different than those of `.click()`.

Comment: See my update above.  This seems to fire off every time a radio is selected.  I need something that only fires when a currently selected item is clicked.  Here is a fiddle using your method... http://jsfiddle.net/BWQED/3/

Comment: @AdamYoungers well that's going to be problematic. When you get to the event handler, the browser will have **already** updated the state of the radio button. To do what you're asking, you're going to have to maintain your own version of the radio button states. (It doesn't matter how the handler is set up; that's just how radio buttons work.)

Comment: @AdamYoungers to put it another way, any event handler for a radio button will *always* see the button as ":checked".  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You bound the event only to the inputs that were initially checked. Remove `:checked` from the first selector and it works as intended (but ugly.)

http://jsfiddle.net/8rDXd/19/

```
$('input').click(function () { 
    $('input:checked').css('background','#FF0000');
    $('input:checked+label').css('background','#ff0000');
});
```

you would of course need to "undo" the css change you made with jQuery to make it go away when the input is unchecked.

```
$('input').click(function () { 
    $('input').css('background','').filter(":checked").css('background','#FF0000');
    $('input+label').css('background','');
    $('input:checked+label').css('background','#ff0000');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8rDXd/20/